# Trouble understanding how JWTs are used with RSA (Man in the middle attack?)

Tags: jwt

I'm having trouble understanding how exactly JWTs are used in conjunction with RSA encryption. This is my current understanding for RSA:

-The client logs makes a post request to the server with his credentials, if the credentials are valid the server signs a JWT using the private key and sends it to the client.

-The client uses the public key to verify the JWT came from the server and then stores this JWT for future requests.

Now does the client just attach this JWT to the header of each get/post request I make to protected routes in order to verify the user? Wouldn't this be vulnerable to a man in the middle attack since they could easily change the contents of the request and the server would have no way to know it's been modified. How am I supposed to hash the header + payload to stop an entity from changing the data like with HMAC?

Comment: *they could easily change the contents of the request and the server would have no way to know it's been modified. ...stop an entity from changing the data like with HMAC?* - I don't understand that point. Why do you think the server wouldn't notice in case of a RSA signature, but would notice in case of HMAC?

Comment: Since I'm simply attaching the JWT that identifies the user in the request header when using RSA there's no checksum on the actual contents of the request. With HMAC I could create another JWT storing the request contents using the secret key, if someone were to then modify the request JWT signature wouldn't match.

Answer (score 2):

The critical piece of information/understanding you seem to be missing here is that JWTs contain a *checksum*, which is a hash dependent on the contents of the JWT.  The server will sign every JWT with its private key before it sends it back to the client, including a checksum.  Upon receving an incoming JWT, the JWT will again compute the checksum based on the contents and compare to the checksum which the token itself contains.  In the event of a man-in-the-middle attack, which attempted to insert or alter the contents of the JWT, the checksum computed would *not* match the value embedded in the JWT.  You might ask next what would prevent the man-in-the-middle from also computing the correct checksum.  Well, MITM can't do that, not without having the server key.  The hash should largely be impossible to reverse engineer out the key used to sign it.  So as long as you defend your server key from being hijacked, the JWT pattern can actually be very secure.

Comment: I understand that it's not possible for an attacker to successfully interfere with the JWT when it's sent from the server to the client initially. However, say the client would like to buy $100 worth of clothing, if he attaches the JWT in the header of a post request something like POST(/store, {"cost":100}) whats to stop someone in the middle from changing cost to say 1,000?

Comment: @Craig If you're asking about the _header_ of the message containing the JWT, then you're not really asking about the JWT.  For avoiding general MITM attacks, you can consider using two way SSL.

Comment: I'm not asking about the header of the message I'm just wondering that since we are simply sending the JWT in the header as merely the authorization the hash isn't being re-calculated and is unrelated to the contents of the request. With HMAC I could send the JWT identifying the user in the header and then another JWT in the body of the post request using the secret key to ensure the contents aren't manipulated. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: I don't follow.  The _server_ is supposed to be the gatekeeper here.  It issues signed JWT tokens with checksums and it validates those checksums.  The client, at best, could add/remove some claims and try to guess the new checksum, but it would almost certainly guess wrongly.

Comment: What I'm thinking in my head is essentially that the client has logged in, the server sent the JWT to the client that identifies them to the server. That JWTs checksum remains constant regardless of what type of request we send to the server right? I'm thinking a different user couldn't change any of the contents of the JWT as that would ruin the checksum, but he could change contents of the request as that doesn't involve the JWT.

Comment: Nope...and that's not what my answer says either.  Every new JWT coming out of the server is always signed with a new checksum _unique_ to its contents.  If the contents change, the checksum also must change.

Comment: @Craig I think I get your point. JWT itself is secured by the signature, but it doesn't secure the request content. But that's not depending on the kind of signature, RSA vs. HMAC (which seems to be the original question)

Comment: @jps Oh, I thought HMAC would be able to re-use the secret key to sign a new JWT over to the server. Why isn't that possible? Does https solve someone being able to modify the request content?

Comment: HMAC uses the same key for signing an verification (symmetric algorithm), therefore you have to keep the secret absolutely secure on the server, no client should know it. And the private key that is used to sign the authorization JWT is also absolutely private to the signing server. And yes, https means the request is encrypted between client and server.